# The Dynamics of an Urn Without Replacement

Tags: probability, distributions, survival, hypergeometric-distribution

**Setup:**

Consider an Urn with $N$ balls, where $M\leq N$ are red and $N-M$ are black.

Let $R_t$ and  $B_t$ denote the event of drawing a red or black ball at time $t$, respectively. Further, let $p_t=P(B)$ and $q_t=1-p_t=P(R)$ such that $P(R_t+B_t)=p_t+q_t=1$ on each trial.

We assume a frequentialist stance on probabilties and define $p_t=\frac{N_t-M_t}{N_t}$. At each time-step $t$, we draw from the Urn *without replacement*. This creates the dynamics, as each draw/trial changes the number of red *or* black balls, and the total amount of balls in the urn, and thus the probability of drawing them.

1. Let $t$ denote the number of draws ${1,2,3,\dots}$
2. We define a $success$ as the event  $B$.
3. Time / number of draws before a success is $T$.

**Useful definitions/statements**:

4. Time of success $T$ is a random variable with density function $f(t)$ cumulative density $F(t)$.
5. The *conditional probability* of success (conditioned on no success) between $t$ and $t+\triangle t$ is given as 
   [$P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t)\approx\frac{f(t)\triangle t}{1-F(t)}$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218947/intuition-behind-hazard-rate/219018#219018).
6. It seems obvious that, for a finite $N$ and $N-M>0$ then $P(t\leq T)$ (the probability that a success has not yet transpired at time $t$) must necessarily converge to zero. E.g. the Urn is emptied until a black ball is drawn.

---

**Questions:**

Generally, I am interested in the dynamics of the following probabilities. E.g. as in writing up simple one (or $n$) step dynamics.

For some $N$ and $M$ such that $M\leq N$ how does the following identities evolve as time moves forward (e.g. more balls are drawn from the Urn)?

**1.** $P(t=T)$ (*Probability of success in trial $t$*)

**2.** $P(t\leq T)$ (*Probability of success before or in trial $t$*)

**3.** $P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t)$ (*Probability of success in $t+\triangle t$, given failure up to $t$*)

**4.** Do any of the above identities (or their log-transform) follow simple [recursive relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) such as $p_{t+\triangle t}=\lambda p_t$? E.g. *"The probability of success at time $t + \triangle t$ depends on $p_t$ via. this simple relation ...*

**5.** Can anyone tell me what kind of littrature asks these questions? I've looked shortly at *waiting time problem* or *first passage problems* but none of them with easy-to-understand intuition of the Urn.

---

**Intuition/Answers:**

**1.** $P(T=t)=(1-p)^{t}p$ and thus follows a geometric sequence.

**2.** $P(t\leq T)\rightarrow0$ for $t\rightarrow\infty$. The speed at which this goes towards zero, must depend on $\frac{N-M}{N}$ - but I can't seem to formulate it rigorously.

**3.** $P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t)$. Assume at time $t$ that $N=4$ and $N-M=1$ thus $p_t=0.25$. Can I deduce what $p_{t+\triangle t}$ is from definition **5.**?

**4.** Don't really have an answer or know where to begin on this. But my intuition is that there are some easy linearities hidden in this setup. E.g. If I know $N$ and $M$, calculating average (expectations) to future probabilities might be possible or even using Bayes.

---

I've tried to be as clear as possible, but I am not a mathmatician, so any calls for clarity are appreciated. [Crosspost to math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065894/the-dynamics-of-an-urn-without-replacement).

Comment: Please *do not* crosspost (you did the same with [your previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249031/relation-between-likelihood-conditional-probability-and-failure-rate)). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette

Comment: I had no idea that was against etiquette. I will delete from math.SE. as I think the question belongs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your first three questions, such draws follow a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) if you draw exactly $n$ balls from the urn, to observe $k$ successes. It follows a [negative hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution) if you draw balls until observing exactly $r$ failures.

Hyprergeometric distribution has the following probability mas function

$$
P(X = k) = \frac{\binom{M}{k} \binom{N - M}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}
$$

that has the following resursive property (as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) and [in this pdf](http://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/2912436/c4.pdf) that refers to Lieberman and Owen, 1961, [*Tables of the Hypergeometric Probability Distribution*](https://statistics.stanford.edu/research/tables-hypergeometric-probability-distribution)):

$$
P(X = k+1) = P(X=k) \frac{(M-k)(N-k)}{(k+1)(N-M-n+k+1)}
$$

It's pretty popular probability distribution so you'll easily find lots of references about it.